# Nativescript - Set Inline Style Programmatic

Tags: styles, nativescript

https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#setinlinestyle

Is there any example of this function?

```
let image = new Image();
image.height = 300dp;
image.setInlineStyle('background-image: url(~/images/my_img.png)')
```

OR

```
image.setInlineStyle('{ background-image: url(~/images/my_img.png) }')
```

Both are not working.

Have I misunderstood the usage of `setInlineStyle`? Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image . URL should be in quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
image.setInlineStyle('background-image: url("~/images/my_img.png")')
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is set the backgroundImage, I'd recommend you to set it this way instead,

```
let image = new Image();
image.height = 300dp;
image.backgroundImage = "url('~/images/my_img.png')";
```

Comment: yeah that sounds good, but I might add more CSS style in future, thanks for the recommendation!